# what are ScriptSig?

Tags: script, input-script

[image]

I was studying bitcoin script, and upon watching this transaction in blockexplorer i was confused , what exactly is ScriptSig and scriptPubKey is of reciever?

According to what I know, the receiver contributes the ScripSig and sender contributes the ScriptPubKey. I cannot understand the function of CHECKSIG operation and what signature does it validate.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG

Comment: The question is very generic, and requires a whole lot to be answered... Also the image has low resolution. We would have to type the numbers from an address or a transaction manually into a block explorer - that's a bit too much :-) I provided a link, where the idea of the scripts is explained. Andreas' book "Mastering Bitcoin" is an amazing book that'll definitely give you additional help. It's freely available online here: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/index.html, see chapters 6 on transactions, and 7 on scripting.